# how to run play framework on windows 7

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2

I tried to install play framework & when I tried to run it see what I got!

```
C:\Users\LAMA>play
Error during sbt execution: Could not find configuration file ‘file:///C:/Users/LAMA/Desktop/New%20folder%20(2)/play-2.2.3/framework/sbt/play.boot.properties’.
Searched:
file:/C:/Users/LAMA/
file:/C:/Users/LAMA/
file:/C:/Users/LAMA/Desktop/New%20folder%20(2)/play-2.2.3/framework/sbt/
C:\Users\LAMA>
```

Even though the file recognized before is found in this path:

```
file:/C:/Users/LAMA/Desktop/Newfolder(2)/play-2.2.3/framework/sbt/
```

Comment: Play doesn't seem to like spaces in it's path on windows for some reason. Life would be much easier if you'd just place it in `C:\play` or something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be spaces in the file path:

```
 New%20folder%20(2)
```

Comment: I have another problem with my first application I put a button in the form but when I press it it didn't work can u help me,plz???
if u say yes I'll upload my app so u can see it

Comment: Had the same problem.. I had the play folder copied to my Program Files, after remove it to a director without spaces it worked.